# Xamarin Forms UWP - Can't Compile with .NET Native tool chain - Error: ILT0032

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, .net-native

I've been developing a Xamarin forms app, but can't seem to build the UWP version in release mode with .Net Native Tool chain enabled.
I get the following error message in the build log whilst trying to compile:

`C:\Users\dherring\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.1\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : System.NotSupportedException: Cannot deserialize type 'Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement' because it contains property 'Bounds' which has no public setter.`

The remaining stack trace: 
    `C:\Users\dherring\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.1\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()
C:\Users\dherring\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.1\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo source, Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError)
C:\Users\dherring\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.1\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : at System.Xml.Serialization.ReflectionAwareCodeGen.WriteReflectionInit(TypeScope scope) C:\Users\dherring\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.1\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterCodeGen.GenerateBegin() C:\Users\dherring\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.1\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Hashtable assemblies, String outputDir, IEnumerable'1 referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, Boolean loadAssembly) C:\Users\dherring\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.1\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer(Type[] types, XmlMapping[] mappings, CompilerParameters parameters, String outputDir, IEnumerable'1 referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, Boolean loadAssembly) C:\Users\dherring\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.1\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer(Type[] types, String outputDir, IEnumerable'1 referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, List'1 wcfSerializers, Boolean loadAssembly) C:\Users\dherring\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.1\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : at SerializationAssemblyGenerator.Program.Main(String[] args) Generating System.Reflection.DispatchProxy proxy code. C:\Users\dherring\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.1\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : ILT0032: Failed to compile serialization code. See the build log for error details.`

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.6), .NetStandard 1.4 in my class libraries due to other restrictions, and as such, I can only go as high as Xamarin.Forms version 2.5.1.527436, which is what's referenced.

I've looked into the UWP Default.rd.xml file, but it doesn't seem to listen to it?

```
<Namespace Name="Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement" Serialize="Excluded" Browse="Excluded" Activate="Excluded" Dynamic="Excluded" XmlSerializer="Excluded" />
```

and

```
<Type Name="Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement" Serialize="Auto">
      <Property Name="Bounds" Serialize="Excluded" Browse="Excluded" Dynamic="Excluded" />
</Type>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you used some nuget package that not be supported by .NET Tool Chain ?

Comment: Well, I assume Xamarin.Forms is, even though it's the one it's complaining about. Otherwise, how would I find out?

Comment: Could you share a simaple sample? or you could test with blank app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm in the process of cherry picking items from my main project over to a blank one. I suspect it's something silly, but the error message is so vague it could be any of my custom controls / views.